# Can I observe changes on Android App Process Priority?

Tags: android, performance

I need to monitor my app process state and do some actions based on the current priority set for the process. Is there any callback can notify the app if the process priority changed?

Comment: manually observe this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was facing was related to an app coming from the task manager to the foreground while its original process was killed. I worked around this by caching the current PID of the running app and compare it when the app comes back from the background. If the PID has changed then the original app process was killed and the app is running on a new process.